# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed (JSP)

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

This piece of code is giving me error that operation can not be performed after result set is closed. I do not understand what is going wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
  String username = request.getParameter("username");
  String password = request.getParameter("password");

    //JDBC CODE
  try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/**", "****", "******");
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from add_user_table where name='"+username+"' and password='"+password+"'");
    if(rs.next())
    {
      String name=rs.getString("name");
      String pass = rs.getString("password");
      if(username.equals(name) && password.equals(pass))
      {
         session.setAttribute("username",username);
         response.sendRedirect("any.jsp");
      }
      else
      {
        response.sendRedirect"any2.jsp?msg=Invalid");
      }
    }
  else
  {
      response.sendRedirect("any2.jsp?msg=Invalid");
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think writing code with a obvious risk of SQL injection is a good habit.

Comment: Stack trace is required. Why are you checking for a match in both the SQL and the following Jaca code?

Comment: As far as I can tell the code shown cannot produce this error. Please post the stacktrace.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's because you are using an if(rs.next) which will only check one instance, which is probably why you are getting the ResultSet closed error. Change it to while(rs.next) to scan through each one.

On a side note, i'd stay clear of Scriplets in your JSP pages, opting instead for JSTL(Java server pages tag library) and EL(Expression Language) code to reference any servlet data, which will be much neater and adhere to the MVC type architecture.

Comment: How could this possibly be true? How could changing `if` to `while` possibly solve a `ResultSet closed` error? This answer doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I'm surprised that a Person with such a high reputation and knowledge would respond in such a manner, without offerering some alternative to the actual question at hand. You clearly felt that it was prudent to downvote my answer, which i have no problem with, but as you can see from my reputation i'm only starting and would appreciate any advice pointers, which will enable me to learn as you once did.